# Problem with save data to multiple model from multiple form in one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have problem with saving data from request which was sent from multiple form in one view. One of them is saved but i cant get rest of data to save in second model. Model Soil has references from Job.

I read a lot of tutorials about saving data from multiple model but i cant find solution for that. I am newbie with programming in ruby on rails.

```
  def create
    @job = Job.new(job_params)
    if @job.save
      @soil = @job.soils.new()
      @soil.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Added'
      redirect_to @job
    end
  end

  private

  def job_params
    params.require(:job).permit(:name, :samples, :duedate, :soil_attributes => %i[shelf count_samples initials])
  end

    {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"WRhC3Dffq290lK5u2tnITJWT244ZLlwoAnm/T1tWdw3/UbUUpIOuB0ziclkuMFnIZ8KWZllFZlQrBP/quyb33g==",
 "job"=>{"soil"=>{"initials"=>"AWO", "shelf"=>"A3", "count_samples"=>"4"}, "name"=>"19-35123", "samples"=>"4", "duedate"=>"2019-05-21"},
 "button"=>""}
```

Job model

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :soils
      before_save :default_value
      validates_presence_of :name, :samples, :duedate
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :soils
      private
      def default_value
        self.archived ||= false
      end
    end

class Soil < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :job
end
```

Comment: Show us your models. Looks like you're inverting some of these relationships. Who belongs to who?

Comment: Updated, thanks for help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to create a parent and child object in one POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980132/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-parent-and-child-object-in-one-post)

Answer (score 1):

This is basically just a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12980775/8844929. I recommend you follow their advice:

Job Model `/app/models/job.rb`:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :soils
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :soil
```

in the `/app/models/soil.rb`:

```
class Soil < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job
```

in `app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb`:

```
def create
  @job = Job.create(params[:job])
  if @job.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Added'
    redirect_to @job
  end
end
```

Since job accepts nested attributes for soil, it'll also save the new soil objects (if they are passed along). You'll likely have to change your form in the `html.erb` file, but this is probably the cleanest way to create a parent and child in a `belongs_to` relationship. You can even update soil objects with params like:

```
{ job: { name: 'thingy', soil_attributes: { id: '2', shelf: 'A4' } } }
```

Documentation can be found here: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

It looks like your parameters are the real problem. Your form should have this for soil creation:

```
<%= form_for @job, do |f| %>
  .. omitting form fields for job
  <%= f.fields_for :soil do |ff| %>
    .. omitting form field for soil
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Many thanks for help. Problem has been resolved after change from job_params to params[:job], but i would like ask how can i set up permitted manually for attributes?I needed add params.permit!

Comment: `params.require(:job).permit(:name, ...other params, soils_attributes: [:id, :shelf, ...other params])`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have associated the two models and that `Soil` `belongs_to` `Job`.  If that is true you can add the params `autosave: true` to the `belongs_to` association in the `Soil` model.

EDIT

Yep, now that I can see your models, this should do what you are looking for:

```
belongs_to :job, autosave: true
```

You may even like to add `dependent: :destroy` as well.  It helps with cleanup:

```
belongs_to :job, autosave: true, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: I added, but what i should in job controller how i can save data?

Comment: `@job.save` should save both `job` and `soil`.  You don't need to add anything to the `has_one` or `has_many ` association in the `job` model.

Comment: I did how you say but still only adding id from job to soil table :(